# Multisampling using Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, antialiasing, multisampling

For some time I was trying to enable multisampling on QGLWidget in order to smooth endges of cuboids that I render but with no success. Here are the code parts that do the work.

1)I am passing a specified format to constructor of GLWidget (which inherits QGLWidget) in order to enable multisampling and set number of samples

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  QGLFormat glFormat;
  glFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);
  glFormat.setSamples(4);

  widget = new GLWidget(glFormat, ui->centralWidget);
  widget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("widget"));
  ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(widget);
}
```

GLWidget *widget is a member of mainwindow class.

2) I am enabling multisampling in initializeGL() method and test if multisampling works

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
  glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
  glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

  GLint bufs;
  GLint samples;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &bufs);
  glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLES, &samples);
  qDebug("Have %d buffers and %d samples", bufs, samples);
}
```

Even though setSamples is set to 4 qDebug prints

```
Have 1 buffers and 8 samples
```

Nothing actually happens the cuboids still have jagged edges, lines are not smooth as well

3) Here is how cuboids are rendered

```
void GLWidget::placeBox(Dimension d, Position p)
{
  Position normal, v1, v2;

glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glLineWidth(1.5);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);
glEnd();

// N = cross( (V1 = gl - gd), (V2 = dl - gd) )
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    v1 = {0, 0, -d.w};
    v2 = {0, -d.h, -d.w};
    normal = crossProduct(v1,v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);

    v1 = {0, 0, d.w};
    v2 = {0,-d.h, d.w};
    normal = crossProduct(v1,v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);

    v1 = {-d.l, 0, 0};
    v2 = {0, 0, d.w};
    normal = crossProduct(v1,v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);

    v1 = {d.l, 0, 0};
    v2 = {d.l, 0, d.w};
    normal = crossProduct(v1,v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);

    v1 = {-d.l, 0, 0};
    v2 = {-d.l, -d.h, 0};
    normal = crossProduct(v1, v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z+d.w);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z+d.w);

    v1 = {d.l, 0, 0};
    v2 = {d.l, -d.h, 0};
    normal = crossProduct(v1, v2);
    glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y+d.h, p.z);
    glVertex3f(p.x+d.l, p.y, p.z);
glEnd();
}
```

GL_LINE_LOOP is used to create frames around cuboids and GL_QUADS for cuboid faces

I am working under Linux Mint, using Radeon HD 7790.

Comment: 8x MSAA is the maximum that desktop AMD GPUs support in non-CrossFire configurations. I get the impression that somewhere your system is configured to override application settings and use the highest MSAA level possible to begin with. One such setting allows you to use 8x MSAA whenever an application requests ***any*** MSAA and disable MSAA altogether when no MSAA is requested (I believe Catalyst Control Center calls it: *"Enhance Application Settings"*). Can you print the results of requesting pixel formats with: 1. No MSAA, 2. 2x MSAA?

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman I configured the settings in catalyst control center and know the number of buffers and number of samples are correct corresponding to QGLFormat. But still and most importantly i don't see any antialiasing on my scene, lines and quads are still jagged.

Comment: I switched to windows and multisampling works properly, looks like the problem was with graphic cards drivers on linux mint.